# I'm trying to set up a Mediawiki automatic notification system

Tags: email, mediawiki, wiki

I'm trying to set up a system using SMW for a small design company, where every day that a client's project is worked on, the designer updates that client's page on the wiki(acting as an impromptu changelog).

Each client is acting as their own category, associated with a template that has an email tag for that individual client.

What I'm trying to do is set up the mediawiki site so that the new page would email out to the client. I'm trying to avoid setting up a notification system that just tells the client to go look at their wiki page, because that would either 
a. Lead to everyone being able to see the worklog of client A.
or 
b. Lead to client A having to register on the wiki. Neither A, nor B is what we'd term as "good".

Does anyone have any advice on setting up a digest system based on an email that is currently on the client's page in the wiki? I repeat, in this ideal system, the client will not end up with ANY sort of access to the wiki, including read-only.

Thank you very much for any available help.

Answer (score 0):

is that possible?, i would suggest downloading the page as an xml and sending him that xml(but it wont get the images, or perhaps getting an image of the page and sending him that

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to write (or hire someone to write) an extension for MediaWiki.  But before you do it, rethink your concept.

First of all, Wiki is about editing, so sending an e-mail on new article creation *only* might be not enough.  What if your employee make a stupid mistake?  What if he forget to use preview before submitting?  On the other hand, spamming your customers on every page update is bad option too.  Consider using [Flagged Revisions extension](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aFlaggedRevs).  Create a new page, read it carefully once again, then flag revision as stable.  Your desired notification extension would send an e-mail on such flagging, allowing you to send e-mails with updates.  Remember that users may have rights for flagging their revisions automatically — disable that.

Categories may have content like any other articles, so they are suitable for storing an e-mail address.

So, back to your question: [ArticleInsertComplete hook](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aHooks/ArticleInsertComplete) is triggered when new page is created.  I'm not sure which hook is triggered when given page is flagged, it may be [ArticleSaveComplete](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aHooks/ArticleSaveComplete).  Your extension should wire to one of these hooks and send an e-mail.  I am not sure how to retrieve a rendered article, but this is certainly possible (in the worst case you can perform a web request to gather HTML, but there must be a better way).